# App Center doesn't show anything in Log Flow

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

In App Center there are "Events" and "Log Flow". I have Events coming in (first picture), but nothing appears in Log Flow (second picture).  What makes Log Flow show information?

Also, I am using TrackEvent such as...

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("Hello World");
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

'**Log flow**' shows the real-time events log.
So it works only while your app is running. Else it will show 'Awaiting data...'

If still no logs here while app is running - events sending is not working for this app.

'**Log flow**' in general used for testing app event sending (Is it send or not...)

[image]